IntelliJ displaying code comments as formatted rich text
I am going through a tutorial in Intellij. This video tutorial shows formatted text in editor. Can anyone help to find how this text added above the class. I tried with the help of comments, changed to Rendered view but it is not showing like tutorial. Below is image


Are you sure that is part of the editor? This feels like something done in video editing. Although formatting documentation comments like this, it would have the same text color as regular comments, and it wouldn't have a light-grey background like in the picture. It could also be a feature of an IntelliJ plugin though.

@Sweeper Please check this video tutorial, instructor doing live coding. For example, at time stamp 4:13
https://youtu.be/40Og3hTV--k?si=Lj6zE7cbdk0-UPqW

It's probably a plugin then. I cannot find that gutter icon in the gutter icon list.

Actually seeing the age of the video, this might just be how documentation comments were rendered in an older version of IntelliJ.

@Sweeper, we got answer. comments support adding html elements which renders in rendered view (Ctrl+Alt+Q)

Okay... I thought you already tried that and didn't like it, since you said "I tried with the help of comments, changed to Rendered view but it is not showing like tutorial". The rendered view is clearly different from the one in the video, no light-grey background and all.

@Sweeper My apologies if I made you misunderstand. What I meant was that I tried using single line comments. i have raised a you track support ticket to get details -
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-354051/Display-text-in-IntelliJ-Editor-in-formatted-way. I will update once i got exact solution for this issue.

That grey background could be achieved using style attribute in the div tag, but I doubt if the speaker did that. You could be right about the plugin or could be a custom theme.

Render Javadocs feature
Javadoc supports HTML tags.
IntelliJ can render that HTML on-the-fly.

On Windows OS, using Ctrl + Alt + Q renders Javadoc comments.
On macOS, Ctrl + Option ⌥ + Q.

See the IntelliJ manual: Render Javadocs
Here's the editable view -

Here's the rendered view -

I tested on IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2.

By the way, Java 23+ supports Markdown syntax in addition to HTML and JavaDoc @-tags.
See: JEP 467: Markdown Documentation Comments
